# to what extent is a reductive group hyperbolic?

Tags: gr.group-theory

The group $SL(2,F)$ where $F$ is a local nonArchemidian field is hyperbolic. Various generalizations of the notion of hyperbolicity have been studied in the literature (I've seen terms like "hierarchically hyperbolic", "relatively hyperbolic" etc.). Which of those classes do groups of the form $G(F)$ where $G$ is semi-simple of higher rank fall into?

Comment: Most likely, none. These property imply that cocompact lattices have a lot of  quotients (and in particular admit infinite normal subgroups of infinite index), while most higher rank groups $G(F)$ admit just-infinite cocompact lattices.

Comment: Semihyperbolic in the sense of Alonso and Bridson (except that their original definition was for finitely generated groups while your groups are compactly generated, but this does not seem to bother you).